# online time series anomalies detection with apache spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, time-series, apache-spark-mllib, anomaly-detection

we have a data pipeline system

apache kafka---->spark steaming----->spark mlib

the data consumed is time series data (e.g. each record  is in the form [key,value,timestamp])

we want to monitor time series anomalies for each key (like twitter anomalies https://anomaly.io/anomaly-detection-twitter-r/)

i.e. we want to train the system (for each key) and we want to detect anomalies online (i.e. if range of values go out of usual range in a specific time on the day for a specific key).

could this be done with apache spark? could k-means help? could we have an example code (scala code)? is their any framework or library?

Comment: Search for Streaming K-Means or Spark ML with Streaming Dataset